# Issue understanding weka apriori algorithm output

Tags: java, weka, data-mining, arff

I'm using the following code in order to find out interesting association rules
on file `data.arff`.

My problem is that I don't know how to interpret the output.
what is the output telling me ?
I would expect rules like [a=1,b=1] -> [c=1]
for example, wich I'm not getting.

```
        //Define ArrayList to Add Clustered Information
        Apriori apriori = new Apriori();
        apriori.setNumRules(10);
        BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("C:\\data.arff");
        Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
        apriori.buildAssociations(data);
        System.out.println("-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-");
        System.out.println("Number of Associations : " + apriori.getNumRules());
        System.out.println("Adding Association Information to ArrayList .."); 
        AssociationRules arules = apriori.getAssociationRules();
        int num = apriori.getAllTheRules().length;
        System.out.println("Num :" + num);

        for(AssociationRule ar : arules.getRules())
        {   
            System.out.println("premise: " + ar.getPremise());
            System.out.println("consequence: "+ar.getConsequence());

            System.out.println("---");
        }
```

**data.arff**

```
@relation Presence-Absence-Representation

@attribute a    {0,1}
@attribute b    {0,1}
@attribute c    {0,1}
@attribute d    {0,1}
@attribute e    {0,1}
@attribute f    {0,1}
@attribute g    {0,1}
@attribute h    {0,1}

@data
1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1
1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
```

and I'm getting the following output:

```
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
Number of Associations : 10
Adding Association Information to ArrayList ..
Num :6
premise: [a=1]
consequence: [e=0]
---
premise: [b=0]
consequence: [d=0]
---
premise: [f=1]
consequence: [d=0]
---
premise: [c=1]
consequence: [g=0]
---
premise: [a=1, d=0]
consequence: [e=0]
---
premise: [e=0, g=0]
consequence: [a=1]
---
premise: [a=1, g=0]
consequence: [e=0]
---
premise: [b=0, e=0]
consequence: [d=0]
---
premise: [b=0, f=1]
consequence: [d=0]
---
premise: [b=0, g=0]
consequence: [d=0]
---
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a dictionary, and look up the terms

- premise
- consequence

to understand how to write them using the `=>` symbol.